# Managed Service Identity (MSI) for Azure Media Services

Tags: azure, access-control, azure-media-services

I want to access an Azure Media Services account from a web app. The documentation that I have read so far says that MSI for Azure Media Services is still not available. Just wanted to confirm this, if it is true/false ?

Another thing, if it is true, do we have any road-map to complete this in near future ?

Answer (score 0):

It is true currently that MSI is not available, but we support Azure AD authentication on Media Services accounts now, and you should be able to enable it through standard AD auth, Oauth 2.0, and JWT tokens.

We are moving our API to be ARM based very soon, where AAD auth is supported also. But the whole ARM team has not upgraded yet to AAD auth 2.0 flow, so they don't even support MSI yet as far as I am aware (I can double check.)

We have some folks who have created samples that uses MSI with Azure Functions to create and submit an Indexer V2 job:  [https://github.com/StratusOn/MSI-Depot](http://%20https://github.com/StratusOn/MSI-Depot)

The sample calls the REST APIs directly to pass the access token.
We have also seen folks implement an ITokenProvider for our existing .NET SDK that works with MSI and hence allows leveraging the .NET AMS SDK and simplifying the code.

Comment: 2 years later, do we have an update on this @johndeu?

Answer (score 0):

@bc3tech,

This works now. Has worked since we moved the v3 APIs fully over to support ARM.

We have not created any tutorials yet, but it should be a similar workflow to these tutorials. Let us know here if you get stuck.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/managed-identities-azure-resources/how-to-use-vm-token

https://github.com/Azure-Samples/windowsvm-msi-arm-dotnet